# How to implement get by id in ASP.NET Core Web API?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

While I am trying to implement get by id API service I am getting all the records rather than one particular  record in ASP.NET Core Web API.

```
[HttpGet("EmployeeId")]
public ActionResult<Employeedatum> Getbyid(int EmployeeId)
{
    if (EmployeeId <= 0)
    {
        return NotFound("not found");
    }

    Employeedatum employeedata = DbContext.Employeedatum.FirstOrDefault(s => s.empid == EmployeeId);

    if (employeedata == null)
    {
        return NotFound("notfound");
    }

    return Ok(employeedata);
}
```

[This is my code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5LTu.png)

Comment: show is `Employeedatum `

Comment: Can u explain clearly please?

Comment: Could you please share `_RegisterBusiness.GetEmployee()` details?

Comment: Can you share your `Employeedatum class` details

Answer (score 0):

> While I am trying to implement get by id API service I am getting all
> the records rather than one particular record in ASP.NET Core Web API.

Well, to begin with your issue, the code snippet you have shared and the screenshot you have attached are different. I am considering your actual code snippet instead of screenshot.

As per your code snippet, I have replace your code within my `DbContext class` and tried to simulate your issue. I am getting the data as expected. Please be sure you have followed below steps accordingly:

Model:

```
public class Employeedatum
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
```

**Note:** Here `[Key]` plays important role to filter data. Make sure your `Employeedatum` class has required `[Key]` therefore, in database as well. You can check as below:

[image]

DbContext:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }
       
        public DbSet<Employeedatum> Employeedata { get; set; }
     


        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Employeedatum>().ToTable("Employees");
        }
    }
```

**Note:** I have tried to reproduce your issue quickly thus I am using this DbFirst approach. But you can use, FluentAPI or Or any other pattern as well.

Controller:

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class EmployeeController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _appDbContext;


        public EmployeeController(ApplicationDbContext appDbContext)
        {
            _appDbContext = appDbContext;
        }

        [HttpGet("Getbyid")]
        public ActionResult<Employeedatum> Getbyid(int EmployeeId)
        {
            if (EmployeeId <= 0)
            {
                return NotFound("not found");
            }

            Employeedatum employeedata = _appDbContext.Employeedata.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == EmployeeId);

            if (employeedata == null)
            {
                return NotFound("notfound");
            }

            return Ok(employeedata);
        }
       

    }
```

**Note:** You even can use [`SingleOrDefault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault?view=net-7.0) in this scenario.

Alternative Way:

You even can use [`Find`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/#finding-an-entity-by-primary-key) to filter or search your entity. So, you can try as following

```
Employeedatum employeedata = _appDbContext.Employeedata.Find(EmployeeId);
```

**Output in postman:**

[image]

If you still need more information, you [check our official document here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/#finding-an-entity-by-primary-key)

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work. But need to check Employeedatum and DB initialization to finger our multiple data return issues.

anyway you can develop it like the below

```
    [HttpGet("EmployeeId")]
    public  ActionResult Getbyid(int EmployeeId)
    {
        if (EmployeeId <= 0)
            return NotFound("not found");

        var employeedata =  DbContext.Employeedatum..GetById(EmployeeId);

        return employeedata ?? NotFound("notfound");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit the code like this

```
[HttpGet("{employeeId}")]
public ActionResult<Employeedatum> Getbyid(int employeeId)
{
    if (employeeId <= 0)
    {
        return NotFound("not found");
    }

    Employeedatum employeedata = DbContext.Employeedatum.FirstOrDefault(s => s.empid == employeeId);

    if (employeedata == null)
    {
        return NotFound("notfound");
    }

    return Ok(employeedata);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this as a Lync query

```
Employeedatum employeedata = DbContext.Employeedatum.where(s => s.empid == EmployeeId).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Do you mean a LINQ query?

Comment: It's not working. Can u suggest another way, please?

Comment: @santhoshkumar when you debug, you get a list of employees right?